# Dropbox delta user ID

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, webhooks

We are receiving the following JSON from dropbox webhook. We don't know what does it mean that delta user information:

```
{
"list_folder": {
    "accounts": [
        "dbid:AAH4f99T0taONIb-OurWxbNQ6ywGRopQngc",
        ...
    ]
},
"delta": {
    "users": [
        12345678,
        23456789,
        ...
    ]
}
```

}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [webhooks documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks) (click on the second tab) covers the meaning of these fields:

> The `list_folder.accounts` list is a list of API v2 account IDs. The `delta.users` list is a list of API v1 user IDs.
>
> Note that only the user IDs and accounts with file changes are provided. Your app is expected to call [/files/list_folder/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http#documentation-files-list_folder-continue) to find out what files changed using the latest cursor your app previously stored for that account. If your app is still using v1, you can call [/delta](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#delta).